# Customize AWS Kibana

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, kibana-4

Currently using **AWS** and **Kibana** (*Version 4.1.2-es-2.0*), the map functionality isn't [available anymore](https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-4-5-3-and-4-1-10). 
But there are some solutions like [this one](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/7717#issuecomment-231931756).

Is there any possibility to access these files in the AWS Kibana environment ?

Answer (score 0):

The same thread you pointed has information about that: "There is no option available on that old of a version of Kibana, sorry"

AWS lags behind with versions in all range of its managed third party software (examples from my experience so far: MySQL, Zeppelin and ES of course). You can either setup your own ES cluster on EC2 or wait until AWS team decides to upgrade its ES and Kibana versions.